# Windows Clicking Issue

Tags: windows, mouse

I'm at my wits end with this thing. I'm on Windows 10 64 bit, and when I left click things, it sometimes registers as two clicks when I only clicked once, and sometimes when I try to drag things, it acts like I double clicked it. When I right click and try to open things in context menus, it acts like I closed the context menu and didn't click anything even though I'm clearly clicking things. This is all sporadic, and when I perform once of those actions, the problem occurs like 25% of the time. Here's a video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZL22cgHkkI&feature=youtu.be 
As you can see, I right click spotify and then click rename, but it just acts like I closed the context menu. Then it starts working again

Comment: try the mouse on a second PC and look if you hae the same. if yes, the mouse seams to have issues

Comment: I'm having much the same problem, but I'm in Windows 7.  I swapped out my mouse and the problem still existed, so it's definitely not the mouse.